# Installing Jupyter Hub and Lab on a GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I opened an account on GCP and have set up a VM there using ubuntu v2204 and a static ip address. The firewall is set up to accept HTTP and HTTPS requests.
I am trying to run jupyter lab on the vm and access it from a remote computer.
I installed Jupyter Hub as explained in https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-the-hard-way/blob/HEAD/docs/installation-guide-hard.md and the process went well without errors.

However, I am not able to access Jupyter lab remotely either using server address:8000 or server address/jupyter: the former times out and the latter gives a 404.
Does someone know how to get around this?

Comment: Why are you connecting on port 8000? My guess is if you followed the documentation, connect using `http://IP-ADDRESS/` The documentation sets up the app on port 8000 and then proxies Internet traffic to the app. If that does not work, edit your question with the Nginx configuration files. If you did not set up the Ngiinx section, then open port 8000 in the VPC firewall. Note: you opened HTTP and HTTPS. That means you opened ports 80 and 443.